# semaphores in java blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

```
public class Watek implements Runnable {
  Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);
  int index = 0;
  int zakres = 0;
  Counter sum;
  private LinkedList < Integer > tablica;
  public Watek(int pivot_index, int chunk, Counter Atomic_var, LinkedList < Integer > tab) {
    index = pivot_index;
    zakres = chunk;
    sum = Atomic_var;
    tablica = tab;
  }


  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      int zm = 0;
      for (int j = index; j < zakres; j++) {
        zm += tablica.get(j);
      }

      sem.acquire();

      sum.add(zm);
      sem.release();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Watek.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

  }
}
```

I'm kind of not sure if i'm putting binary semaphores in the right place beacuse I'm adding value of 1 dimentional matrix by 100 threads and when I'm using semaphores sometimes results are wrong like for matrix[100000] of ones I sometimes get 100000 sometimes 98000 but when I'm checking for low amount of threads like 2,4 everthing is ok when higher risk also higher so this is fault of semaphores or there is bug somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't create your semaphore instance within the runnable.  Each instance of the runnable has its own unique semaphore in this case, and therefore you're not blocking as you would expect.

Instead, create the semaphore outside the runnable, and pass it to runnable object (e.g. via constructor), so each instance of the runnable uses the same semaphore.